# Symfony 4 + Doctrine: organize entities in subfolders

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make a website with Symfony 4 and Doctrine. I'm a complete beginner (both with Symfony and PHP in general), so I apologise if my question is trivial.

I want to create a database with doctrine, which means that I have to create classes in `src/Entity`. But I also want to add forms to the site, and they also require classes in `src/Entity`. I'd like to separate these classes in two subfolders: `src/Entity/database` and `src/Entity/forms`. I tried to edit `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` as follows:

```
doctrine:
    #...
    orm:
        #...
        mappings:
            App:
                #...
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/database'
                prefix: 'App\Entity\database'
```

But I when I use `bin/console make:entity Entity` it creates the file in `src/Entity` and gives the following error:

```
[ERROR] Only annotation mapping is supported by make:entity, but the
    <info>App\Entity\Entity</info> class uses a different format. If you
    would like this command to generate the properties & getter/setter
    methods, add your mapping configuration, and then re-run this command
    with the <info>--regenerate</info> flag.
```

When I run `bin/console make:entity Entity --regenerate` it says:

```
[ERROR] No entities were found in the "Entity" namespace.
```

I also tried `bin/console make:entity database/Entity`, but it fails with:

```
 [ERROR] "App\Entity\Database/Entity" is not valid as a PHP class name (it must start with a letter or underscore,
     followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores)
```

If I do the same with a backslash (`database\Entity`) it creates a `DatabaseEntity.php` file in the wrong directory and gives the same error as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful, because with such approach you might mess your architecture up. This question is a bit opinionated, but I'm gonna tell you how we make it with entities and forms.

First, my strong belief, Entities and Forms should be separated. Therefore, we contain Entites in `src/Entity` and Forms in `src/Form`. The connection between them is a FormType, we contain those in `src/FormType`.

Here's an example User entity contained in `src/Entity/User.php`:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    /**
     * @param null|string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername(?string $username): User
    {
        $this->username = (string) $username;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }


    /**
     * @param null|string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword(?string $password): User
    {
        $this->password = (string) $password;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, we need a user to be able to register. For this we create a FormType and a Form. Take a look at `src/FormType/User.php`:

```
namespace App\FormType;

use App\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as NativeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class User extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return BaseType::class;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // This maps `Entity\User::username` to the respective field
        $builder->add(
            'username',
            NativeType\EmailType::class,
            ['label' => 'username']
        );

        // This maps `Entity\User::password` to the respective field    
        $builder->add(
            'password',
            NativeType\RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
                'invalid_message' => 'nonMatchingPasswords',
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'password again'],
                'type' => NativeType\PasswordType::class,
            ]
        );
    }

    // This tells Symfony to resolve the form to the `Entity\User` class
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Entity\User::class]);
    }
}
```

And now the Form itself, it's `src/Form/UserRegistration.php`:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as NativeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;

class UserRegistration extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        // Note this!
        return FormType\User::class;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'fields' => ['username', 'password'],
                'translation_domain' => 'forms',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And a final stroke on this. In `src/Controller/Registration.php` we do this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    Form\UserRegistration::class,
    $user = new Entity\User()
);
```

The rest (how to handle forms etc.) you know. If you don't, read Symfony docs, they cover it perfectly.

I have cut out / edited some sensitive or non-essential things from this example. For instance, we do not bind `password` to `password`, we ask for plain password and then encrypt it. I have not tested the above, so it might not be stable. But for a demonstration on how your architecture should be done it's a good example, IMO.

Comment: @gp_sflover why am I answering the wrong question here? Care to elaborate more? I think I'm correcting the fundametal error that OP makes. If I were to simply answer why `No entities were found in the "Entity" namespace.` is thrown, OP would never learn the good approach to programming.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because at a first read I haven't got your point. Anyway, as you already said, this question is a bit opinion based and without much context to give a better answer. PS: I noticed only now you are the same guy of a previous debate, that's was a case :-), no problem, I'm not offended, I always like constructive and positive discussions. Have a good day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a `bin/console` command I have to use to create the form class files or can I edit them directly?

Comment: I dont usually use the console (only to clear cache and migrate the db), so I can't say. I always edit the files directly.